# How to include a dynamic class as well as a conditional dynamic class to a child component in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a `GenericButton` component that I need to pass a couple of props into. One is for the class it will use and another is a class that will apply if the button is disabled. I read the Vue docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html, but I am still having issues. in the docs, they say you can do this to bind a class to a JS expression, and even bind multiple classes.

```
<div
  class="static"
  v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }"
></div>
```

I pass a prop called `injectedClass` and one called `isDisabled`. This is my button:

```
<button
    :disabled="isDisabled"
    :class="{ injectedClass, disabled: isDisabled }"
    @click.stop="handleClick"
  >
    {{ text }}
  </button>
```

The disabled class applies how I would expect, but my passed `injectedClass` isn't applied. The `injectedClass` is applied if I do this:

```
<button
    :disabled="isDisabled"
    :class="injectedClass"
    @click.stop="handleClick"
  >
    {{ text }}
  </button>
```

It isn't even working if I do this:

```
:class="(injectedClass, { disabled: isDisabled })"
```

My question is how can I apply the class I pass through to my component and also conditionally apply my disabled class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax)

`:class="[injectedClass, { disabled: isDisabled }]"`

Comment: Thank you! I was confused because when I tried to save it as :class="injectedClass, {disabled: isDisabled}" it autocompleted with parenthesis instead of brackets. Anyway, thank you for the help!